# Not enough information to infer type variable T in recyclerView using DataBinding

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding

On writing `DataBindingUtil.inflate`, the above mentioned error is shown. Kindly do help me out. Here is my code:

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(private val subscribersList: List<Subscriber>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return subscribersList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(subscribersList[position])
    }

}

class MyViewHolder(private val binding: ListItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    fun bind(subscriber: Subscriber){
        binding.nameTextView.text = subscriber.name
        binding.emailTextView.text = subscriber.email
    }
}
```

I want to resolve this error by using binding